# ⊕: What is the meaning of the $\oplus$-symbol?

Tags: notation

What does this mean?
$$a \oplus b$$

I've seen this notation in a text about one-time-pads. Is it XOR?

Comment: Yes, in the context of one-time pads it is certainly the bitwise exclusive-or of two bitstrings.

Comment: Post this as an answer, if you want to.

Comment: I actually only see a question mark. Consider looking through the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) and finding it there.

Comment: Is $\oplus$ (LaTeX/MathJax `\oplus`) the symbol you want? It would work better across different devices than directly entering the symbol. (Also @ChaseRyanTaylor)

Comment: Now the problem is, that this question is more difficult to google. I assume that this question raises quite often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the context of one-time pads it is certainly the bitwise exclusive-or of two bitstrings.